# QGIS blurs labels

Tags: qgis, labeling

[image]

I'm recently having trouble with getting my roads labels to show up in a QGIS map. I need to label every road. In the past the labels would show up with no issue but now i cannot see anything.

What am i doing wrong?

I've checked the label properties multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The blur effect seems to have been created by a white buffer around the label, with some transparency. Since you can't see the labels (except for the road 12), they may also be printed in white.

[image: White label with white buffer]